# Creating a rest API for user profiles

Tags: rest

What is the best practice to create a REST API for CRUD of user profiles?

I see some API that ops for

```
https://www.a.com/userProfile12339485
```

and some will have

```
https://www.a.com/user?profile=12339485
```

Not sure what the standard way or is there one?

Answer (score 1):

Since all URIs are linked in REST (as opposed to coded in or configured in the client), there is no real difference.

Opting for the second choice may give you the additional benefit of being compatible with HTML Forms with GET action.

A popular third choice is sometimes:

```
/profile/12345
```

Some frameworks may give you explicit support for this variant, but in the end it doesn't *really* matter, since you should be linking to these URIs anyway if you are doing "REST".